# Javascript remove style without giving it a id or a class

Tags: javascript

so I have this HTML code where I hide the body of the website using

```
    <style>
        body{
          display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <body>
    <p>Something..</p>
    </body>
```

but now I want to remove this using Javascript without giving the body an ID or a class. As a solution I've tried the following but it is not working.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].removeAttribute("style");
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Quick question: Why do you want to hide the website in the first place?

Comment: Hi, It's for a simple web app I'm trying to build. I just simplified the question so it is easier to understand my issue.

Comment: Ok. Why don't you want to use classes?

Comment: you can directly set the properties of `document.body.style`.
`document.body.style.display = 'block'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [`document.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body)'s [`display` style property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to [`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset):

```js
document.body.style.display = "unset"
```

```html
<style>
  body {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <p>Something..</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the style tags added in your HTML, you have to select it using `document.getElementsByTagName` and call `remove` method to its nodes.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0].remove();
```

```css
body {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Something..</p>
```

**If you want to  set style to the element**

If you just want to set the `display` style of body tag, you can do this with javascript using.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.display
```

**More Generic Solution**

```js
const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
const targetStyles = {
  display: 'block',
}
Object.entries(targetStyles).forEach(([style, value]) => body.style[style] = value);
```

```css
body {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Something..</p>
```

**What is the issue with your script?**

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].removeAttribute("style");
```

This script selects the `body` tag from HTML and removed the inline style added to the body. Its will work for below template, but not for your requirement.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].removeAttribute("style");
```

```html
<body style="background: blue;">
  <p>Something..</p>
</body>
```